# Scrapy runs Spider before CrawlerProcess()

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I have generated a new project and have a single Python file containing my spider.
The layout is:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import *
import json
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import unicodedata
from scrapy import signals
from pydispatch import dispatcher
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class TrainerItem(Item):
    name = Field()
    brand = Field()
    link = Field()
    type = Field()
    price = Field()
    previous_price = Field()
    stock_img = Field()
    alt_img = Field()
    size = Field()

class SchuhSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "SchuhSpider"
    payload = {"hash": "g=3|Mens,&c2=340|Mens Trainers&page=1&imp=1&o=new&",
               "url": "/imperfects/", "type": "pageLoad", "NonSecureUrl": "http://www.schuh.co.uk"}
    url = "http://schuhservice.schuh.co.uk/SearchService/GetResults"
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}

    finalLinks = []

    def start_requests(self):
        dispatcher.connect(self.quit, signals.spider_closed)
        yield scrapy.Request(url=self.url, callback=self.parse, method="POST", body=json.dumps(self.payload), headers=self.headers)


    def parse(self, response):
        ... do stuff ..

    def quit(self, spider):
        print(spider.name + " is about to die, here are your trainers..")

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(SchuhSpider)
process.start()
print("We Are Done.")
```

I run this spider using:

```
scrapy crawl SchuhSpider
```

The problem is I'm getting:

> twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable

This is because the spider is actually running twice. Once at the start (I'm getting all my POST requests) then it says "SchuhSpider is about to die, here are you trainers..".

Then it opens the spider a second time, presumably when it does the process stuff.

**My question is: How do I get the spider to stop automatically running when the script runs?**

Even when I run:

```
scrapy list
```

It runs the entire spider (all my POST requests come through). I fear I'm missing something obvious but I can't see what.

Comment: have you heard of ScrapyD? you can run (run multiple spiders) and stop spiders via an HTTP api.

Comment: I haven't, but I'll check it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mix two ways how to run a spider. One way is as you do it now, i.e. using

```
scrapy crawl SchuhSpider
```

command. This way, don't (or better you don't have to) include the code

```
process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(SchuhSpider)
process.start()
print("We Are Done.")
```

as it's inteded only if you want to run spider from script (see the [documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script)).

If you want to retain the possibility to run it either way, just wrap the above code like this

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(SchuhSpider)
    process.start()
    print("We Are Done.")
```

so that it doesn't run when the module is just loaded (the case when you run it using `scrapy crawl`).

Comment: Ah, can you tell I'm not a Python developer? Thank you for pointing that out, big help.